# Adding a geopackage (gpkg) to GeoServer through REST API

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, rest, curl

I'm trying to use the REST API to upload a GPKG file (SQLite with *vector* data) into GeoServer with curl but I always get `Error auto-configuring coverage`.

The (wrong) command I'm currently using is
`curl -v -u <USR>:<PASSWORD> -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/geopackage+vnd.sqlite3" --data-binary @<PATH&FILENAME.GPKG> "http://<IP>:<PORT>/geoserver/rest/workspaces/<MYWORKSPACE>/coveragestores/<FILENAME>/file.geopackage%20(mosaic)"`

After @IanTurton’s comments below, I noticed that I'm using the wrong endpoint since "geopackage%20(mosaic)" is for *raster* data only.

Which is the right endpoint I have to use with a vector gpkg?

I tried searching online but I found nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mixing the comment by @AndreaAime and the answer by @IanTurton, I finally made a working curl for Geopackages containing SQLite vector data:

`curl -v -u <USR>:<PASSWORD> -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/x-sqlite3" --data-binary @<PATH&FILENAME.GPKG> http://<IP>:<PORT>/geoserver/rest/workspaces/<MYWORKSPACE>/datastores/<FILENAME>/file.gpkg`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can add geopackages in the same way as [you add shapefiles](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/stores.html) but with the file extension `.gpkg`:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/zip" --data-binary @codepoint.zip http://localhost:8080/geoserver-2.17.2/rest/workspaces/ian/datastores/cp/file.gpkg
```